# Is there a way to perform resumable uploads using gsutil cp (not REST APIs) across different machines?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gsutil, google-cloud-storage

When `gsutil cp` fails, we can resume the session by running the exact same command on the same machine (session is tracked via ~/.gsutil/tracker-files). However, when we switch machines, this directory no longer exists, so when running the same command, the session is not resumed. See [Resumable Uploads (CLI)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#command-line) and [Background On Resumable Transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/ScriptingProductionTransfers#background-on-resumable-transfers).

Alternatively, I see that with [Resumable Uploads (REST APIs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#rest-apis), we can generate a session URI and pass this URI to different commands. However, I don't see the option to pass in a session URI in the `gsutil cp` options listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options).

With this information, is the only way to resume the session via gsutil CLI by sharing the ~/.gsutil/tracker-files volume among different machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `gsutil` and `gcloud alpha storage` use local tracker files to handle resuming uploads, so yes, you'd need to copy those files to a new machine if you wanted to resume the operation elsewhere.

As you noted, the API itself provides a "session URI" that you can use to query the upload progress and resume the upload from anywhere, but I don't believe specifying it explicitly is an option in either command line utility.

Our client libraries do support it, though. If recovering uploads from different machines is a regular part of your workflow, you could perhaps write a small, custom uploader program. Here's an [example of how to use resumable uploads with the C++ client](https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-storage/latest/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1storage_1_1Client.html#a8918b5f338d91607b06d5107965ed35e). The key section is:

```
    gcs::ObjectWriteStream stream =
    client.WriteObject(bucket_name, object_name,
                       gcs::RestoreResumableUploadSession(session_id));
    std::cout << "I should start writing from byte " << stream.next_expected_byte();
```